# csv does not seem to appear due to reference error

Tags: javascript, html, json, csv, google-apps-script

I am quite new to this all, so i am pretty sure this is a simple oversight on my part, but i cant get it to run.

When i deploy the code below and click on the button, it does not do anything. When i inspect the html in my browser, it says "userCodeAppPanel:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: csvHTML is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick"

When i run the function csvHTML from Code.gs, I can see the expected results in my Logger.log, so it seems the problem does not lie in my code.gs

What i am trying to achieve is showing the csv results in html. When all works fine, i will want to work with the data in some other way.

Attached below is my code.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- styles -->
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("styles.css").getContent(); ?>

<div class="content">

  <h1>csv representation</h1>

  <input class="button" type="submit" onclick="html();" value="Refresh" id="refresh"><br>
  <div id="tabel"></div>
  <svg class="chart"></svg>

</div>

<!-- javascript -->
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("chart.js").getContent() ?>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("main.js").getContent() ?>

<script>

function html()
{
var aContainer = document.createElement('div');
    aContainer.classList.add('loader_div');
    aContainer.setAttribute('id', 'second');
    aContainer.innerHTML = "<div class='loader_mesage'><center>Fetching csv list. Please be patient!<br /> <br /><img src='https://i.ibb.co/yy23DT3/Dual-Ring-1s-200px.gif' height='50px' align='center'></img></center></div>";
    document.body.appendChild(aContainer);

google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(showTable)
           .csvHTML();
}

function showTable(tabel)
{
document.getElementById("tabel").innerHTML = tabel;
var element = document.getElementById("second");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
</script>
```

and Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html")
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


// Fecth Data and make a csv output.

function csvHTML()
{
var query = "{ 'query': 'SELECT * FROM `<some table>` limit 1000;', 'useLegacySql': false }";
var job = BigQuery.Jobs.query(query, <projectName>);
var json = JSON.parse(job);
var tabel = json2csv(json); 
Logger.log(tabel)
return tabel;  
}

function json2csv(json, classes) {
  var headerRow = '';
  var bodyRows = '';
  classes = classes || '';

  json.schema.fields.forEach(function(col){
    headerRow +=col.name+",";
  })

  json.rows.forEach(function(row){
   row.f.forEach(function(cell){
      bodyRows +=cell.v+",";
    })

                  })
     return headerRow + bodyRows }
```

Comment: `csvHTML` is a standalone function, not a method of whatever the method `.withSuccessHandler` returns

Comment: Relevant documentation link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run . Based on that, it seems like the code here is correct.

Comment: Could you change function `html` to `html1` and republish a *new* version?

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks, i tried that, it now says "Uncaught ReferenceError: html1 is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick"

Comment: Try moving the `<script>...</script>` portion to the head  section and republish a new version.

Comment: Also provide (or remove from your testing code) styles.css, chart and main.js

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks a lot man! It seemed that the styling was really getting in the way of the code haha.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to the suggestions by TheMaster, i rewritten it into the following:

index.html:

```
<!-- javascript -->
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

function html()
{
var aContainer = document.createElement('div');
    aContainer.classList.add('loader_div');
    aContainer.setAttribute('id', 'second');
    aContainer.innerHTML = "<div class='loader_mesage'><center>Fetching csv list. Please be patient!<br /> <br /><img src='https://i.ibb.co/yy23DT3/Dual-Ring-1s-200px.gif' height='50px' align='center'></img></center></div>";
    document.body.appendChild(aContainer);


google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(showTable)
           .csvHTML();
}

function showTable(tabel)
{
document.getElementById("tabel").innerHTML = tabel;
var element = document.getElementById("second");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>


<div class="content">

  <h1>csv representation</h1>

  <input class="button" type="submit" onclick="html();" value="Refresh" id="refresh"><br>
  <div id="tabel"></div>
  <svg class="chart"></svg>

</div>
```

Code.gs has not been modified.

It appears that the `<?!= htmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("styles.css").getContent(); ?>` and other createHtmlOutputFromFile were getting in the way. Eventually i need these, but I will figure out how to incorporate that at a later stage.

Thanks for all the advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have zero experience with Google Apps Script, so take this with a grain of salt.

Looking at their [documentation for `BigQuery`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#run_query), it seems you are not querying the database correctly. I am surprised by your claim that `Logger.log()` shows the correct output. It does not appear that it should work.

In case I am right, here is what I propose you change your `Code.gs` file to:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html")
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


// Fetch Data and make a csv output.

function csvHTML() {
  var results = runQuery('SELECT * FROM `<some table>` limit 1000;');
  var tabel = toCSV(results);
  Logger.log(tabel);
  return tabel;
}

/**
 * Runs a BigQuery query and logs the results in a spreadsheet.
 */
function runQuery(sql) {
  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'XXXXXXXX';

  var request = {
    query: sql,
    useLegacySQL: false
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }
  var fields = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.name;
  });
  var data = [];
  if (rows) {
    data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    fields: fields,
    rows: rows
  };
}

function toCSV(results) {
  var headerRow = results.fields.join(',');
  var bodyRows = results.rows.map(function(rowData) {
      return rowData.map(function(value) {
        // for proper CSV format, if the value contains a ", 
        // we need to escape it and surround it with double quotes.
        if (typeof value === 'string' && value.indexOf('"') > -1) {
          return '"' + value.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"';
        }
        return value;
      });
    })
    .join('\n'); // join the lines together with newline characters
  return headerRow + '\n' + bodyRows;
}
```

Reminder: I have not tested this, I'm purely writing this based on my knowledge of Javascript and their documentation and sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate reply! I have adapted the code, but i still get the same error originating from the index.html ("Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1)"

So it seems i am still messing up somewhere there. I checked my logger.log again and based on what my code is in Code.gs for the function csvHTML it does give me the desired results back.